# How to manage state?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, state

```
  class Book {
    constructor () {
      this.state = { 'isInitializing': true, 'isFlipping': false, 'isZooming': false, 'isPeeled': false, 'isZoomed': false, 'isFlippable': false }
      this.mode = _viewer.getMatch('(orientation: landscape)') ? 'landscape' : 'portrait'
      this.plotter = { 'origin': JSON.parse(`{ "x": "${parseInt(d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width) / 2}", "y": "${parseInt(d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height) / 2}" }`) }
    }
  ...
```

I have a `Book` class with many states. The book uses CSS3 animations to turn over pages or pinch to zoom etc., during which its state changes from `isFlipping: false` to `isFlipping: true`, `isZoomed: false` to `isZoomed: true`.

There are mutually exclusive situations, for example when `isZoomed: true` the `isFlippable` must be `false`.

And then with event listeners:

```
  const delegateElement = d.getElementById('plotter')

  const handler = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    event.preventDefault()

    switch (event.type) {
      case 'mouseover':
        _handleMouseOver(event)
        break
      case 'mouseout':
        _handleMouseOut(event)
        break
      case 'mousemove':
        _handleMouseMove(event)
        break
      case 'mousedown':
        _handleMouseDown(event)
        break
      case 'mouseup':
        _handleMouseUp(event)
        break
      case 'click':
        _handleMouseClicks(event)
        break
      case 'dblclick':
        _handleMouseDoubleClick(event)
        break
```

And then later on depending on state: do stuff.

```
  const _handleMouseOver = (event) => {
    if (!event.target) return
    // do stuff depending on state, meaning lot of `if else` or `switch` `case ` statements.

  }    
  const _handleMouseOut = (event) => {
    if (!event.target) return
    // do more stuff.
  }

  const _handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    if (!event.target) return
    // do stuff depending on state.
  }
  …
  // more events as per list above… and so on.
```

Now this is going to make my code very unwieldy and horrible to read. :-(

I wonder what path should I take to organize logic (pattern) and handle state of the book per events as they are fired and animation completed (`transitionend` etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach as i know to manage js state is to use state management libraries like  [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/) or [Redux](http://redux.js.org/).

Take a look at Flux pattern in general and its implementations.

Comment: ELI5 anyone? :-)

Comment: you can see here http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/CoreConcepts.html  for redux example . But i recommend to you take a look at mobx https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html  . It's easy for beginners.